# Dynamic UIPickerView with multiple TextField

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am using `UIPickerView` with `UITextField`. It is working when I use only one `UITextField`.
What I want is to use multiple `TextField` for one dynamic `pickerview`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;
self.transitTF.inputView = picker;
self.theData = @[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four"];
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return self.theData.count;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return  1;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return self.theData[row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
self.transitTF.text = self.theData[row];
[self.transitTF resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This is what I use with one `textField` only.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add **tag property** for each `UITextField`.  In this case `self.pickerView.inputView.tag` you may use to find which textfield is using in current moment and you may fill picker with correct values